# Usage of "to set the timer" and "to time"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, articles

1. I am going to cook. I need to set a (or "the"?) timer for half an hour as I started roasting.
2. Can I say "I need to time the roast for half an hour"?
3. How do you usually say to express that idiomatically?

Answer (score 1):

'To time' as a verb is usually used to suggest measuring a time, not setting one.

You might say:

> I'm going to time myself cutting these carrots to see how quickly I can do it!

So, saying 'time the roast' conjures the image of you with a stopwatch waiting to find out how long it takes the roast to finish cooking!

Instead, you would say something similar to the sentence in your first point:

> I need to set the timer for half an hour when I put the roast on.

Comment: Contextually it makes perfect sense to say *time the roast*.  The day you see a roast running a footrace let me know.  Only then will agree that timing a roast is confusing.

Comment: It isn't something I have ever heard anyone say. If somebody told me they were going to 'time the roast' I would think they were going to measure how long it took to cook, not set a timer for cooking it. The dictionary definition of the verb 'to time' is 'measure the time taken by'.

Comment: "You’ve got to time the roast or it will get overdone." The sentence is from Cambridge Dictionary. They use "to time" and not "timer". Is it ok?

Comment: Yes, but that's using it in a different way. If you look where that example comes from, it says 'to measure the seconds, minutes, and hours for something to happen or someone to do something'. That's different from setting a time using a timer. 

'To time' can also mean to arrange or synchronize. That's the sense in which you would say you have to 'time a jump correctly' in a video game, for example. You might say you have to time the roast so that it's done at 12:00, for example.

Comment: @EdwardPhillipHealy Cambridge disagrees. People say *time the pizza* or *time the roast* all the time.  It means *set a timer*.  Vova - feel free to time the roast.  It only ever means one thing in that context.  In your example *time the roast* means *set a timer for X number of minutes.*

Comment: Time - *verb* - plan, schedule, or arrange when (something) should happen or be done. (i.e. In 45 minutes the roast should be taken out of the oven).  If you can effectively tick those 45 minutes off in your head, no need to set a timer.  If not, set a timer.  Technically EdwardPhillipHealy has a point.  *To time* does not directly reference a timer.  However, most timings of things use a timer.

Comment: @EllieK No, they don't disagree. If you read the context of that quoted example. To time a roast can mean to cook it such that it will be finished cooking at a specific time - in other words to arrange the roast for a particular time. In that example the specific time is before it 'gets overdone'.

I have never once in my entire life heard anyone say they were going to 'time the roast' or 'time the pizza' in the context of setting a timer. It sounds very, very strange to my ear although I would understand what was meant by it. Perhaps it's a regional thing, or maybe it's American English?

Comment: @EdwardPhillipHealy - To time a roast can mean to make plans to have the roast done at a particular time, forty five minutes from now for example.  One would set a timer for that.  Why you choose to interpret the OP as meaning that the roast should be removed at a predetermined time (i.e. 3:30) is beyond my comprehension.  That is not at all what the original poster has asked.  Reread her post.  You are way off base here and beating a dead horse in order to defend an incorrect position.  You're new here and I am sure your contribution is appreciated.  Be still and learn.

Comment: Given that I already said you might be right and it might be something I just haven't been exposed to, there really is no need to be so rude.